# How to modify a reference variable by another class?

Tags: dart, flutter

The problem is when I give my variable (String) as a parameter to a function it stay as it is. It's like there is only passing by value.

```
void main() {
  String quote = "search";
  print(quote);
  f(quote);
  print(quote);
}


void f(String txt) {
  txt = "find";
}
```

Result is :

```
search
search
```

What I want is :

```
search
find
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart uses parameter passing by value, so you'd expect to see that.

You could wrap the primitive in a class and implement the mutating function on that class. That way you are logically grouping the function that can modify the data, with the data.

```
main()
  Quote quote = Quote('search');
  print(quote.quote);
  quote.f();
  print(quote.quote);
}

class Quote {
  String quote;

  Quote(this.quote);

  void f() {
    quote = 'find';
  }
}
```

Comment: what about if I want to pass my variable which is declared in my class to another function in another class for the purpose to change its value ?

Comment: You pass the class. That other thing can modify the class members directly (subject to privacy restrictions) or call a function on the class to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use a List as such without creating a new class

```dart
void main() {
  List quote =  ["search"];
  print(quote[0]);
  f(quote);
  print(quote[0]);
}


void f(List txt) {
  txt[0] = "find";
}
```